# Scope of De Morgan's law?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have a statement like this:

(~p ^ ~q) V (p ^ q)

If I understand this correctly, I can apply the law to both sides separately while leaving the OR in the middle intact. Leaving this:

(p V q) V (~p V ~q)

Is this valid? (as opposed to taking the negation of the entire statement)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not valid. Using the model of Boolean algebra for these expressions, the bottom expression is tautologically true, whereas the top one is not (e.g. it's false for $p$ true and $q$ false).

Comment: I did not think to compare the statements in this way. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

You did not apply de Morgan correctly. As it stands, if $p$ is true and $q$ is false then $(\urcorner{}p\wedge{}\urcorner{}q)\vee(p\wedge{}q)$ is false and $(p\vee{}q)\vee(\urcorner{}p\vee{}\urcorner{}q)$ is true. The reason is that de Morgan doesn't say (your first disjunct, for example)
$$
\urcorner{}p\wedge{}\urcorner{}q\Leftrightarrow{}p\vee{}q
$$
but rather
$$
\urcorner{}p\wedge{}\urcorner{}q\Leftrightarrow{}\urcorner(p\vee{}q)
$$

Comment: An important distinction that I feel dumb for not realizing. Thank you!